# How to Create a Scheduled Post in Django?

Tags: python, django, post, time

I would like to publish the shipment according to the specified date and time.

For example, when I send the article today, I want it to be published automatically when the time comes tomorrow. (or at any date and time)

How can I do it?

Relevant part of the model:

With this model, date and time are determined for post.

**models.py**

```
published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Yayımlanma Tarihi",)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def post_index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        post_list = post_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(author__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(author__last_name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 5) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('sayfa')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, 'post/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: Celery isn't really required. All you have to do is filter out the posts whose `published` date is in future.

Comment: @xyres So how do I do that? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want to publish a post on 1st December, 2019. So, you'll save that post with the `published` date set to 1st Dec, 2019.

But since that post hasn't been *"published"* yet, you don't want it to appear on your website. So, all you have to do is filter it out and only select those posts whose `published` date is before the current time.

Example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now() # get the current time

# only select the posts which are `published` before `now`
post_list = post_list.filter(
    published__lte=now
).filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query) |
    Q(content__icontains=query) |
    # ... etc ... 
).distinct()
```

Comment: It means, I should not set `auto_now_add` in models.py ?

Comment: What is `lte` in `published__lte` ?

Comment: @Progam Yes, `auto_now_add` shouldn't be set for publish date so that users can manually chose the date on which to publish an article. And, `lte` means `lesser than or equal to`. So, in this answer we are selecting those articles whose publish dates are lesser than or equal to `now` i.e. before `now`.

Comment: Is there a Way ( like `__lte` ) `to filter` all the future posts ?

Comment: @Progam There are `gt` and `gte`. Go through [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt) to familiarise yourself with the api.